# Modelling grooves in a wall

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to model buildings that have grooves along the walls. The grooves are mostly horizontal, but they bend near the windows or other openings. Here is an example of such grooves:

https://www.google.com/maps/@45.3212853,8.4228467,3a,60y,31.79h,107.28t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sgWGW5CRiyoz0ygHEJxdoNA!2e0!7i16384!8i8192

[image]

Modelling the horizontal grooves is quite easy, but I'm not sure what would be the best way to work to get the angled ones. At first I though about putting edges along them, then beveling and extruding those back, but it's hard to get good topology. Then I tried making them all horizontal, then cutting through for the angled ones - but this seems cumbersome when I have to do it for many different patterns (ok for one building, but I have many to do, and they're not all the same).

What's my best option to model the grooves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create your horizontal grooves:

[image]

Cut the non-horizontal with a knife:

[image]

Select all the edges that need to be bevelled, bevel:

[image]

Extrude faces along normals:

[image]

Comment: I did something similar, but less clean: this way you get perfect topology. Thank you!